# Infinite do-while loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while

There is an infinite loop going on in my code and I'm confused as to how to fix it. If someone could point me in the right direction or help me out then that'd be really appreciated. Thanks.
Here's the method:

```
public static void random(){
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 11); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    if (guess == rand){
        do {
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + "."); 
            System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Yay!"); 
        } while (guess == rand); 
    }
    if (guess < rand){
        do {
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low. Guess again"); 
        } while (guess!= rand);
    if (guess > rand){
        do {
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high. Guess again");
        } while (guess > rand);
    }
```

Comment: Why would printing a message change whether the guess was too low?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. It should be very easy to spot.

Comment: @Andrew I really doubt this student has been taught to use a debugger

Comment: Exactly.  The do...while loops don't include any code to change `guess`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int guess = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
do {
    guess = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
    if (guess == rand)
        System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Yay!"); 
    else if (guess < rand)
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low. Guess again"); 
    else
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high. Guess again");
} while (guess != rand);
```

Comment: sure.  For OP - No need for a loop within a loop.  In fact, the loop within a loop will run forever without prompting you again for another answer.  Just think about what each case is and how it can fit into only one set of conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the loop is still an infinite loop and doesn't terminate

Comment: I've made some changes.  Now the loop should terminate if you correctly guess the number.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in an infinite loop because of your while loops. If the user guess is lower than rand, your code will enter the while loop and continue infinitely. Here's a possible solution

```
public static void random(){
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 11); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
    boolean guessed = false;

    while(guessed == false){
    int guess = input.nextInt();

    if(guess == rand){

        System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + "."); 
        System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Yay!"); 
        guessed = true;
    }
    if(guess < rand){

            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low. Guess again"); 
                guessed = false;
    } 
    if(guess > rand){

            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high. Guess again");
            guessed = false;
    }
    }
}
```